# Mapping list name to another value

Tags: r, python

I have lists like this:

```
Action=[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]
a=[A,B,E,I]
b=[C,D,F,G,H]
```

So, I want to get the action vector corresponding to a and b, that's mean like this

```
Action=[a,a,b,b,a,b,b,b,a]
```

How can I do it in R or python?

Comment: Everybody assumes here, that "A, B, C..." are strings. Is this true or do they stand for variables containing other elements? Also: Are `a` and `b` distinct lists and contain all elements of `Action`? What should happen if an element turns up in both lists or none?

Comment: Actually, here A, B,C ... are strings. And a, b, c... contain few strings. From a,b and c a new group is created that is Action. But it doesn't mean that the Action contain all the strings of a an b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming these values are characters.

You could do the following in R

```
A <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I')
a <- c('A','B','E','I')
b <- c('C','D','F','G','H')

Action <- character(length(A))
Action[which(A %in% a)] <- 'a'
Action[which(A %in% b)] <- 'b'

Action
# [1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "a" "b" "b" "b" "a"
```

And you could use list comprehension in Python

```
A = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
a = ['A','B','E','I']
b = ['C','D','F','G','H']

Action = ['a' if i in a else 'b' if i in b else None for i in Action]

print(Action)
# ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In R, use `ifelse` like this:

```
ifelse(A %in% a, "a", "b")
## [1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "a" "b" "b" "b" "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can use a dictionary:

```
Action = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
a = ['A','B','E','I']
b = ['C','D','F','G','H']

d = {}
for elem in a:
    d[elem] = 'a'

for elem in b:
    d[elem] = 'b'

result = [d[action] for action in Action if action in d]

print(result)
```

Which Outputs:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a']
```